SQLalchemy - Calling specific table value function from mssql
Having trouble calling SQL table value function in python using sqlalchemy, with specific where clause.  Would ideally also specify columns to call.
Goal is to pass parameters into function and create a dataframe with resulting table result.
Code below:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text, func, null, and_, or_, select
import pandas as pd
query= (select([func.Custom.tfnXXX(213, 107301)])
        .where(
                and_(func.PXXX > 0,
                or_(func.WXXX == '',func.WXXX == None))
                )
        .apply_labels()
        )
engine = create_engine(
    'mssql+pyodbc://server/database?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server&ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly')

with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(query).fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=query.c.keys())

Attempted to follow syntax from sqlalchemy docs, but getting below error.  Not sure how to proceed.
ArgumentError: Column expression, FROM clause, or other columns clause element expected, got [<sqlalchemy.sql.functions.Function at 0x1cc2102e700; tfnXXX>]. Did you mean to say select(<sqlalchemy.sql.functions.Function at 0x1cc2102e700; tfnXXX>)?


You could try calling .read_sql_query() with a plain text parameterized query and a tuple of parameter values, e.g., something like df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM tfnXXX(?, ?)", engine, params=(213, 107301))

This used to be valid in 1.4 or maybe earlier:
select([func.Custom.tfnXXX(213, 107301)])

In 2.0 you need to just pass in the columns as arguments like this (ie. no list):
select(func.Custom.tfnXXX(213, 107301))

You can find more information about this change in the migration guide: select-case-now-accept-positional-expressions
